Identity for curvature tensor
I need to show the following idetnity, where $R$ is riemannian curvature tensor of a manifold $(M,g)$ and $x,y,z,t\in T_pM$:
$$
\partial_\alpha\partial_\beta\{R(x+\alpha t,y+\beta z,y+\beta z,x+\alpha t)-R(x+\alpha z,y+\beta t,y+\beta t,x+\alpha z)\}\bigg|_{\alpha,\beta=0}=6R(x,y,z,t)
$$
where we set $R(a,b,c,d):=g(R(a,b)c,d)$. A hint want me to use the symmetries of curvature tensor and Bianchi identity, but I don't know where to start to using them. What's more, I don't quite know how to deal this partial derivative for a scalar product of vector fields.
(Also, this is one exercise, and the author says that with this one can prove that sectional curvature determines uniquely the curvature tensor, but I also don't know how to do)

First, the second $y$ on the right hand side should be $t$. As for the exercise itself, $R$ is multilinear, so you can expand each of the two $R$ terms on the left hand side into $16$ terms. By multilinearity, every term will have a coefficient of the form $\alpha^i\beta^j$ for $0 \leq i, j \leq 2$. Which terms will remain once you take the two derivatives and set $\alpha = \beta = 0$?

@MichaelAlbanese Thanks a lot! I've solved it, it is just many computation. I have confused this notation with multivariable functions, but now everything is clear!

You should write a solution below. To simplify the computation, instead of expanding the two $R$ terms into a total of $32$ terms, you can just keep the ones which will remain after taking the two derivatives and setting $\alpha = \beta = 0$ (there should only be $8$).

From the multilinearity on each argument of $R(a,b,c,d)$ (the multilinearity in first three arguments are from curvature tensor, and the fourth argument is from riemannian metric), we can split the LHS to 16 terms, e.g.
\begin{align}
R(x+\alpha t,y+\beta z,y+\beta z,x+\alpha t)&=R(x,y,y,x)+\alpha R(t,y,y,x)+\beta R(x, z,y,x)+\alpha\beta R(t,z,y,x) \\
&+\beta R(x,y,z,x)+\alpha \beta R(t,y,z,x)+\beta^2 R(x,z,z,x)+\alpha\beta^2 R(t,z,z,x)\\
&+\alpha R(x,y,y,t)+\alpha^2 R(t,y,y,t)+\alpha\beta R(x,y,z,t)+\alpha^2\beta R(t,z,y,t)\\
&+\alpha\beta R(x,y,z,t)+\alpha^2\beta R(t,y,z,t)+\alpha\beta^2 R(x,z,z,t)+\alpha^2\beta^2 R(t,z,z,t)
\end{align}
Then doing the partial derivative is easy, because the above expression as a function of $\alpha,\beta$ is just a linear function, so
$$
\partial_\alpha\partial_\beta\bigg|_{\alpha,\beta=0}R(x+\alpha t,y+\beta z,y+\beta z,x+\alpha t)=R(t,z,y,x)+R(t,y,z,x)+R(x,z,y,t)+R(x,y,z,t)
$$
For another part in LHS, we don't need to calculate again. Because the position where $\alpha,\beta$ appear are the same with the first part, so we just need to rename the answer for the first part as $t\to z$ and $z\to t$, we get
$$
\partial_\alpha\partial_\beta\bigg|_{\alpha,\beta=0}R(x+\alpha t,y+\beta z,y+\beta z,x+\alpha t)=R(z,t,y,x)+R(z,y,t,x)+R(x,t,y,z)+R(x,y,t,z)
$$
so the LHS should be
\begin{align}
LHS=&R(t,z,y,x)+R(t,y,z,x)+R(x,z,y,t)+R(x,y,z,y) \\
&-R(z,t,y,x)-R(x,t,y,z)-R(z,y,t,x)-R(x,y,t,z)
\end{align}
Then to simplify the expression we need the symmetries of curvature tensor:

$R(a,b,c,d)=-R(b,a,c,d)$
$R(a,b,c,d)+R(b,c,a,d)+R(c,a,b,d)=0$ (Bianchi identity)
$R(a,b,c,d)=-R(a,b,d,c)$
$R(a,b,c,d)=R(c,d,a,b)$

Now we simplify the LHS:
\begin{align}
LHS&=R(t,z,y,x)+R(t,y,z,x)+R(x,z,y,t)+R(x,y,z,t)\\
&+R(t,z,y,x)+R(t,x,y,z)+R(y,z,t,x)+\underbrace{R(y,x,t,z)}_{=-R(y,x,z,t)=R(x,y,z,t)} \\
&=2R(t,z,y,x)+2R(x,y,z,t)+R(t,y,z,x)+R(x,z,y,t)+R(t,x,y,z)+R(y,z,t,x)\\
&=4R(x,y,z,t)+\underbrace{R(t,y,z,x)+R(y,t,x,z)+R(t,x,y,z)}_{=0}-R(x,y,t,z)+R(x,y,t,z)+R(t,x,y,z)\\
&=4R(x,y,t,z)+R(t,y,z,x)-R(x,y,t,z)+R(t,x,y,z)\\
&=5R(x,y,z,t)+\underbrace{R(t,y,z,x)+R(y,z,t,x)+R(z,t,y,x)}_{=0}-R(z,t,y,x)\\
&=6R(x,y,z,y).
\end{align}
The LHS of the formula is just sectional curvature, because note that the first and third entries are same, and second and fourth entries are same. So if we know all sectional curvature, then we know the LHS, then we know the curvature tensor. This means, from the curvature to sectional curvature, we don't lost any information.
